# Deactivate Air app created in AS3 after next Monday?

Tags: actionscript-3, licensing, air, trialware, time-trial

I have an application deployed in Air, written in AS3 that the client wants to install and test, I have developed a simple license app, but he is pushing for a full license which he said he will fully pay on next Monday.

How would you create a procedure in AS3 to deactivate application next Monday? How secure will it be? Will simply changing machine date bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the machine date will easily bypass your security mechanism. You need something more robust, which cannot be controlled by anybody other than you.

If your application is going to run connected to the web, you might be able to poll a remote server to see if the application is allowed to run or not. This is more flexible in that you can control the validity of the application without embedding dates into it.

There might even be off-the-shelf commercial components that do this for you.

But a more serious problem is that you have reason to distrust your client. Maybe you can collect part of the money when you deliver a limited-period beta and take it on good faith that he'll give you the remainder later.